# How do I share files and folders between computers with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I am talking about secure file sharing with a password. I once found a guide that did just that, creating a separate user account with a password whose only purpose is another computer to login through it and read/write to a shared folder and nothing more.

It also explained how to hide it(properly, no .bat or registry hacks) from the logon screen so that you automatically login to your main Administrator account and don't have to choose between the two accounts. Unfortunately, many "simple" guides have appeared and obscured that one as I can no longer find it.

I can create a new user account with a password very easily, but I cannot do the following.

- Hide the account from logon screen.
- Properly configure the Security and Sharing tabs of a folder's properties.
- Only computers behind my router can view the connected computers for increased security for file sharing.

I would really appreciate helps about this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...

Why would you not use the "Homegroup" feature of Windows 7? In the Control panel under Network and Internet --> Network and Sharing Center, you have the ability to create a secure network where you decide the pc's that can share files and folders with;

IIRC, basically you give a name to your network and then it assigns a password that you then use to set up the other pc's to be able to access the new HomeGroup (very easy to do - you just log onto the other machine and have it 'join' the newly created HomeGroup using the assigned password).

That way, you don't need to set up any extra user profiles...